# how to covert a text file in json format using shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell

sample text

```
 [08/12/2016 01:26:17 kup01 -  NBU status: 96, EMM status: No media is]
```

expecting output

```
$json ="[{""date"":""08/12‌​‌​‌​/2016"",
          ""time"":‌​""‌​01‌​:26:17"",
          ""ho‌​st""‌​:"ku‌​p01",
          "sta‌​tu code":"09",
          "emm status":"No media is""
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
-bash-4.1$ sh test
{
"date":"08/12/2016"
"time":"01:26:17"
"host":"kup01"
"status code":"96,"
"emm status":" No media is"
}
-bash-4.1$ cat test
#!/bin/bash

SHELL_OUPTUT="[08/12/2016 01:26:17 kup01 - NBU status: 96, EMM status: No media is]"

echo -e "{
\"date\":\"$(echo $SHELL_OUPTUT|sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'|awk '{print $1}')\"
\"time\":\"$(echo $SHELL_OUPTUT|sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'|awk '{print $2}')\"
\"host\":\"$(echo $SHELL_OUPTUT|sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'|awk '{print $3}')\"
\"status code\":\"$(echo $SHELL_OUPTUT|sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'|awk '{print $7}')\"
\"emm status\":\"$(echo $SHELL_OUPTUT|sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'|awk -F : '{print $NF}')\"
}"
-bash-4.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
echo "08/12/2016 01:26:17 kup01 - NBU status: 96, EMM status: No media is" | awk '{print "$json =\"[{\"\"date\"\":\"\"" $1    "\"\", \"\"time\"\":‌​\"\"‌​" $2 "\"\", \"\"ho‌​st\"\"‌​:\"" $3 "\", \"sta‌​tu code\":\"" $6 "\", \"emm status\":\"" $10" "$11" "$12"\"\" }]"}'
```

Comment: for u sysntax i am not getting output